# MySQL .NET Connector 6.9.8

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I recently had to uninstall and reinstall the MySQL suite, including the connectors for MySQL.

Apparently, the .NET connector never properly uninstalled and when I went to reinstall the connectors, the .NET connector didn't appear in the installer package for MySQL. I went through a myriad of steps to try and remove the package.

I used the Programs and Features uninstall options, CMD msi removal options, removing every entry related to the Connectors from my registry with regedit, as well as the built in removal/repair/change tools in the MySQL msi packages.

I finally got the program to disappear from the programs list, but when I try and install the package again it still says it's installed. I have completely ran out of all ideas as to how to remove this package.

Does anyone know of a way to essentially nuke this program from my computer? Either that or an alternative to allow me to connect C# in Visual Studio 2015 to my MySQL database?

Answer (score 2):

Connector/Net is a fully-managed ADO.NET driver for MySQL.

Starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the MySQL for Visual Studio integration. That functionality is now available in a separate product called MySQL for Visual Studio available using the MySQL Installer for Windows (see http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html).
Please read this reference from MySQL

Comment: That is the one I used to install the MySQL suite both times. However, nothing within it allows me to properly remove/repair the .NET connector. However, I did manage to get a connection to my DB through the VS plugin, so thank you for that tip.